# PE file: Debug directory of type IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_VC_FEATURE

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, executable, portable-executable, debug-symbols

I compiled a vanilla exe using Visual Studio 2015. Besides the expected debug directory of type `IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_CODEVIEW`, I also found a second one of type `IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_VC_FEATURE`.

I could not find information regarding what data it contains and what it is used for. Could anybody explain or point me to a source explaining it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

when you compile with /GL or link time code generation compilers later than vc 2010 emits an extra debug directory that contains vcfeature  these store some counts of pre-vc 110  /GS counts /sdl counts and guardN counts

dumpbin /headers will show the details of this feature 0xc

```
:\>dir /b
printf.cpp

:\>cat printf.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
void main (void) {
    printf("%x\n%d\n%u\n%f\n%g\n%s\n%c\n",256,100,-1,2.2,45.87,"hi",97);
}

:\>cl /Zi /W4 /GL /Ox /analyze /nologo printf.cpp
printf.cpp

Generating code
Finished generating code

:\>dumpbin /headers printf.exe | grep -A 10 "Debug Directories"
  Debug Directories

        Time Type        Size      RVA  Pointer
    -------- ------- -------- -------- --------
    5A7F2A78 cv            3C 0004529C    43E9C    Format: RSDS, xxx59}, 1, printf.pdb
    5A7F2A78 feat          14 000452D8    43ED8    Counts: Pre-VC++ 11.00=0, C/C++=194, /GS=194, /sd
l=0, guardN=193  <<<<<<<<<<<<<
    5A7F2A78 coffgrp      28C 000452EC    43EEC    4C544347 (LTCG)
```

for starters these are all defined in windows headers

13 id == coffgrp as already shown  created by lint time code generation

14 is created if you do incremental linking **/LINK /LTCG:INCREMENTAL**

here is a dummy debug directory

```
Debug Directories(4)
Type       Size     Address  Pointer
cv           53       463cc    457cc    
(    12)      14       46420    45820
(    13)     29c       46434    45834
(    14)       0           0        0
```

dumpbin /headers pogo_vcfeature.exe | grep -A 8 "Debug Directories"

```
 Debug Directories

        Time Type        Size      RVA  Pointer
    -------- ------- -------- -------- --------
    5AD58258 cv            53 000463CC    457CC    
    5AD58258 feat          14 00046420    45820    
    Counts: Pre-VC++ 11.00=0, C/C++=202, /GS=202, /sdl=0, guardN=201
    5AD58258 coffgrp      29C 00046434    45834    
    4C544347 (LTCG)
    5AD58258 iltcg          0 00000000        0
```

windows headers

```
:\>echo %cd%
C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.16299.0

:\>grep -ir -B 12 -A 4 IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_VC_FEATURE *
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
km/ntimage.h:#define IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_VC_FEATURE       12
km/ntimage.h-#define IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_POGO             13
km/ntimage.h-#define IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_ILTCG            14
km/ntimage.h-#define IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_MPX              15
km/ntimage.h-#define IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_REPRO            16
--
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
um/winnt.h:#define IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_VC_FEATURE       12
um/winnt.h-#define IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_POGO             13
um/winnt.h-#define IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_ILTCG            14
um/winnt.h-#define IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_MPX              15
um/winnt.h-#define IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_REPRO            16

:\>
```

Comment: How did you know that? Where can I find info on other types, e.g. 13 (0xd)?

Comment: @blabb  I too am interested in pointers to details of the type 0xD and 0xC debug data, as well as any documentation of how one knows for certain how many debug directories are in a PE file.

Comment: @stackoverflowwww and ReluctantBIOSGuy  i editied in the answer to address these queries